# The algebra generated by a class

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an arbitrary class of subset of $\Omega$. Define the smallest algebra, $\alpha(\mathcal{C})$, that includes $\mathcal{C}$ as: 
(i) $\mathcal{C} \subset \alpha(\mathcal{C})$ 
(ii) If $\mathcal{B}$ is some other algebra contanining $\mathcal{C}$, then $\alpha(\mathcal{C}) \subset \mathcal{B}$

Now I need to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\sigma(\alpha(\mathcal{C}))$, where $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. 
My attempt is: since $\mathcal{C} \subset \alpha(\mathcal{C})$, this implies $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subset\sigma(\alpha(\mathcal{C}))$, but I don't know how to show $\sigma(\alpha(\mathcal{C})) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{C})$, any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that $\alpha(C)\subseteq \sigma(C)$? Because then you are done.

Comment: Since every sigma algebra is algebra, $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is another algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$, then by definition $\alpha(\mathcal{C}) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{C})$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.